# Autorize php to modify a text file on host

Tags: php, authorization

I have a php script on my webhost, GoDaddy, and I want to modify a text file. But it gets blocked, I think it's a problem of authorization but I don't know how to solve this.

```
<?php 
  $var= "test";
  $fileopen = fopen("file.txt", w+);
  fwrite($fileopen,$var);
  fclose($fileopen);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is not with PHP but with the access control management on the server. You don't tell us the error you get, but I guess that you are denied write access to those files. Check the rights of the corresponding files and directory on your server and tweak them as needed to let the web server process access those files.

How to do it is very much dependent on the server's operating system, on the identity under which the web server process is running and on the kind of administrative rights you have yourself. Without further information, it is difficult to say more. Your provider must have some kind of documentation about how you can set up directory and file access rights.